# Graph with Highcharts in new window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I'm using php to connect to a database and get some data to create a graph with highcharts.I have done that but I want to display this graph in a new window.This window opens when the user clicks a button.How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try anything with code ? what was your experience ? were you facing any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a new window and insert there a container with a chart, for example in this way:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var chartWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "left=0,top=0,width=600,height=450"),
        chartContainer = document.createElement("div");

    chartContainer.setAttribute("id", "container");

    Highcharts.chart(chartContainer, {
        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3]
        }]
    });

    chartWindow.document.body.appendChild(chartContainer);
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a235bh1z/